# Rails - ArgumentError in BookingsController#create wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm really struggling with the above error on my Rails app. It highlights the Bookings Controller and in particular this part of the 'create' action -

```
if ( @event.bookings.sum(&:quantity) + @booking.quantity ) > @event.number_of_spaces
        flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end
```

Here's the full Controller code -

bookings_controller.rb

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    # booking form
    # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
    @booking = @event.bookings.new
    # which person is booking the event?
    @booking.user = current_user
    @booking.quantity = @booking.quantity
    @total_amount = @booking_quantity.to_f * @event_price.to_f

end

def create
        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f

    if ( @event.bookings.sum(&:quantity) + @booking.quantity ) > @event.number_of_spaces
        flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end

    if @booking.save
        if @event.is_free?
        flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
        begin
            # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
            Stripe::Charge.create(
                amount: @event.price_pennies,
                currency: "gbp",
                source: @booking.stripe_token,
                description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}"
            )

            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        rescue => e
            @booking.destroy  # delete the entry we have just created
            flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
            render "new"
        end
     end
  end
end


private

def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
end



end
```

The error pops up when I'm attempting to complete a test booking.

Comment: Can you update your question with all the code from the `create` method and any private methods you use in this method?

Comment: Can you update your question with the test code?

Comment: There's no test code. I mean a test booking with Stripe.

Comment: The error shows you have an error with a call to the `BookingsController#create` method, but nowhere in your code shown do you call this. How is this occurring? It is just when you hit the create route from a browser? Or are you calling `BookingsController.new` somewhere (which is not part of the typical Rails workflow)?

Comment: Try dropping the `&` on `@event.bookings.sum(&:quantity)`. #sum is a method for an ActiveRecord Relation that expects a symbol or string representing a field.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this:

```
@event.bookings.sum(&:quantity)
```

I suppose that you are trying to determine the total quantity of the bookings for a particular event?

A nice way to do that is:

```
@event.bookings.reduce(0) { |i, b| i + b.quantity }
```

And of course, this should be a method in the Event model, rather than be in the controller:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  def total_bookings
    self.bookings.reduce(0) { |i, b| i + b.quantity }
  end
end
```

And then the line in your controller becomes

```
if ( @event.total_bookings + @booking.quantity ) > @event.number_of_spaces
```

Comment: Hi, having introduced the above method into my model I'm now getting the following error 'nil can't be coerced into Fixnum'. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the error on the same line? I would check to make sure than none of your bookings have a nil quantity (and perhaps that none of your events have a nil number_of_spaces). If that was the problem, make sure you have validations in the model for those fields.